# Helidon quickstart Docker build not finding parent specified in pom.xml

Tags: docker, helidon

When I build the example in Maven it works fine; however when I try to do the docker build, it errors out.  Has anyone else come across this or have a fix?  I can build other docker images just fine.  thanks in advance.

Here is my command line build results:

```
    S:~/eclipse-workspace/helidon-quickstart-se$ docker build -t helidon-quickstart-se .
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  65.54kB
    Step 1/13 : FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as build
     ---> e23b595c92ad
    Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /helidon
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 479d1d20bfa8
    Step 3/13 : ADD pom.xml .
     ---> Using cache
     ---> d945f45c3d4c
    Step 4/13 : RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip -Declipselink.weave.skip
     ---> Running in 8b058d39dad3
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/helidon/applications/helidon-se/2.4.2/helidon-se-2.4.2.pom
    [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
    [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for io.helidon.examples:helidon-quickstart-se:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact io.helidon.applications:helidon-se:pom:2.4.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/helidon/applications/helidon-se/2.4.2/helidon-se-2.4.2.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 7, column 13
     @
    [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]   The project io.helidon.examples:helidon-quickstart-se:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/helidon/pom.xml) has 1 error
    [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for io.helidon.examples:helidon-quickstart-se:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact io.helidon.applications:helidon-se:pom:2.4.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/helidon/applications/helidon-se/2.4.2/helidon-se-2.4.2.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 7, column 13: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Temporary failure in name resolution -> [Help 2]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
    [ERROR] [Help 2] 'http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException..'
    The command '/bin/sh -c mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip -Declipselink.weave.skip' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/se/guides/02_quickstart

mvn -U archetype:generate -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeGroupId=io.helidon.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=helidon-quickstart-se -DarchetypeVersion=2.4.2 -DgroupId=io.helidon.examples -DartifactId=helidon-quickstart-se -Dpackage=io.helidon.examples.quickstart.se

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something, but isn't this simply a very basic problem with your connectivity to Maven Central?  From the stack trace you posted:

```
Could not transfer artifact io.helidon.applications:helidon-se:pom:2.4.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/helidon/applications/helidon-se/2.4.2/helidon-se-2.4.2.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 7, column 13
```

But, as you can see, of course, the artifact [most certainly does exist](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/helidon/applications/helidon-se/2.4.2/).  Perhaps whatever is doing the fetching is behind a network proxy?